# How can I add a UIButton as a UIBarButtonItem using StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I use a toolbar on a swift project and somehow it has a segmented control as a BarButtonItem, which is working perfectly.

[image]

[image]

What I need to do now is add 2 UIButtons under FutureButton, using a stack view if possible. It seems possible since its pretty much the same of the segcontrol that is there as another BarbuttonItem.

I tried a lot of different solutions suggested on similar questions but I can't add anything to it, even another segcontrol for testing purposes, but no luck in any.

Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Edit: add app screenshot

Comment: do u have any screenshots or draw somewhere and add here. that helps to give answer

Comment: added a screenshot of the page I want the change on. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this way
   Here is the hierarchy

```
-> UIToolBar 
      -> UIBarButton 
         -> UIView 
           -> UIStackView(vertical with 15 spacing)
             -> 2 UISegmentedControll (you can change as per you need)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, but xcode won't let me drop a View inside barButtonItem ...

Comment: you have to drag and drop the UIStackView directly inside the UIView.

Comment: I wish I could drop the UIView :)

Comment: you can drop for sure